# Image doesn't display properly. FIlls an area when not instructed to do so

Tags: php, html, css, image, web

As a reference, http://www.rdesignmedia.com/sweetb is how I want the page to appear except it is missing the logo.   When the logo image is inserted it then appears to look like this http://www.rdesignmedia.com/sweetbee .

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Please add your code, as we cannot help you with nothing to work with.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm on mobile and don't have access to the code at the moment.  When you load the pages could you "View Source"? 

Else, I could get it to you when I get home later tonight.

Comment: Can you update the question as the second link is a error 404. Can you explain in more detail how the logo is *meant* to be looking, and how the way it currently looks is not the same? just saying, *"this is how it looks"* and *"I want it to look like this"* leaves a lot of interpretation without clear description of what ***this*** actually is. Thank you. .

Answer (score 1):

Still need some code clarification on the code?!

- Are you writing this code from scratch, or using an environment to put the site together?  If so, is it online site, or a package like Dreamweaver, or other WSIWYG web editor?
- I used a tool like: TextWranger on OS X, and there is a similar tool called Notepad++ for Windows, and of course "diff" on a Linux box.  These tools can be used to find differences in the code between two pages.

In the pages you referenced, there are places that look fishy, and would definitely cause a different layout.  For example:

- In the Welcome section, the header has, two pieces of code between the pages.  There is a  and in the other page there is  which would explain the image problem.
- There is a TON of CSS, in the styles/screen.css file, way to much for me to try to understand right now.  However, you might want to identify the problem sections and look for the ID or NAME parameters in the HTML code that matches the same in the CSS source to see if it makes sense what is going on.  Many times the order of HTML statements and referring to the wrong CSS, misspelling, or assigned parent can cause a layout to really go wonky.

I would recommend using the suggested tools above to compare the documents.  Skip over the obvious changes (purposeful), and then look at the other changes in the problem areas.

Comment: That's for the reply.   I didn't design the site so I'm not exactly sure.    I have the source code at home. I'm on mobile right now.  Would you be able to "View Source"/"Inspect Element" through your browser in the mean time?  Or else I can post the code later on when I get home./

Comment: The "sweetbee" page no longer loads.  I will be happy to look at it.  Let me know when it returns.

Comment: Hi Jewettg,  sorry for the delay. The alternate link and issue can be seen at the following link.  Thanks for your time. http://rdesignmedia.com/sweetb2/